# Decrypt message using Diffie-Hellman key exchange

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to decrypt some message using a shared secret generated with a Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm X25519.

The server says the messages they sent `are encrypted using symmetric key encryption generated from a Diffie-Hellman key exchange`

I am using the package [cryptography](https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography) to generate a KeyPair, I then send the public key of this keypair to a server which creates a shared secret with the public key I sent and a private key of their own. They then send back the public key on their end, along with a nonce and an encrypted message. I then form a shared secret on my end with my private key and their public key.

My question is, how can I use this shared secret and nonce to decrypt the message?

I am generating my initial key pair as

```
final algorithm = X25519();
final myKeyPair = await algorithm.newKeyPair();

// Get the public get
var myPublicKey = await myKeyPair.extractPublicKey();
```

I then build a public key with the bytes sent by the server.

```
var bytesFromServer = List<int>.....

var serverPublicKey = SimplePublicKey(bytesFromServer, type: KeyPairType.x25519);
```

And lastly I build the shared secret with

```
final sharedSecret = await algorithm.sharedSecretKey(
      keyPair: myKeyPair,
      remotePublicKey: serverPublicKey,
);
```

The docs of the server say: `This shared secret should then be used to decrypt the data field in the response` but I can't find a way or decryptor that will allow me to use the secret along with the nonce they also send from the server.

The SecretKey class, which is the shared secret itself, does not provide any decrypting, and I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: I'm not a cryptography expert, but isn't key exchange just a mechanism to securely transfer a shared secret key, which you then are supposed to use with a specific symmetric cipher (e.g. `AesCtr`, which does offer a `decrypt` method)?  Does your server documentation specify which cipher is used to encrypt the message?

Comment: @jamesdlin That's what I was confused about. I am no crypto expert either. The docs don't mention what the cipher is. It only talks about the key exchange and then says the message should be decrypted using the shared key.
Is there maybe a specific cipher that works for Diffie-Hellman?

Comment: Edit: I contacted the company that runs the server and they replied with `The symmetric cipher is the shared secret that's generated via Diffie-Hellman`.

Comment: You probably need to specifically ask them which encryption algorithm is used.

Comment: @jamesdlin I was able to do it without knowing their encryption algorithm. I ended up using another package which does provide what I needed. Please refer to the answer I posted below

Comment: @tapizquent not sure if you are still struggling with this, but im using this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/diffie_hellman. Quite easy to use: https://xeertz.com/diffie-hellman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using two other packages:

For decrypting and key generation I'm using [pinenacl](https://pub.dev/packages/pinenacl). For base58 decoding I'm using [bs58](https://pub.dev/packages/bs58)

```
final sessionConnectPrivateKey = PrivateKey.generate();
final encodedSessionPrivateKey = base58.encode(
  sessionConnectPrivateKey.toUint8List(),
);

var box = Box(
  myPrivateKey: PrivateKey(base58.decode(encodedSessionPrivateKey)),
  theirPublicKey: PublicKey(base58.decode(encodedServerSessionPublicKey)),
);

// We are able to decrypt because the message was encrypted using
// a similar box with our public key and the server's private key
var decryptedMessageBytes = box.decrypt(
  ByteList.fromList(base58.decode(encodedData)),
  nonce: base58.decode(encodedNonce),
);

var decryptedMessageString = String.fromCharCodes(decryptedMessageBytes);

var decodedPayload = jsonDecode(decryptedMessageString);
```